# Paint integer using drawString without assigning it to a string

Tags: java, string, graphics, int, paint

**Problem:** I need to have an integer that can be changed to be painted on screen.

**What I Want To Do:** Label an X Axis on a chart

**Variables Used:**

- lengthCountArray = An int[] array
- calcXWidth(lengthCountArray) = the amount to move along when painting the next integer

**Current Code:**

```
for(int a = 1; a < lengthCountArray.length; a++){
            x = 50 + calcXWidth(lengthCountArray);;
            y = 450;

            g.drawString(s, x, y);

        }
```

**What I've Tried 1:**

```
for(int a = 1; a < lengthCountArray.length; a++){
            String s = String.valueOf(a); 
            x = 50 + calcXWidth(lengthCountArray);;
            y = 450;

            g.drawString("" + s, x, y);

        }
```

Comment: *Issue is, you can't change a string after assigning it :(*

**What I've tried 2:**

```
for(int a = 1; a < lengthCountArray.length; a++){
            x = 50 + calcXWidth(lengthCountArray);;
            y = 450;

            g.drawString("" + <int a>, x, y);

        }
```

If you require any further information, please do not hesitate to ask! Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't. You need to draw it as a `String` using `drawString`, and then, when the number changes, you need to call `repaint` to indicate that your UI needs to be repainted, and then when you paint the screen again, the new number will be drawn.

Comment: For me it's not clear. When you want to draw an int, then you can do `g.drawSting(String.valueOf(theInt), x, y)` - what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments I saw this post, which was the resolution to the problem.

"For me it's not clear. When you want to draw an int, then you can do g.drawSting(String.valueOf(theInt), x, y) - what's wrong with that?" –  Marco13 Mar 5 at 22:42

Thank you for the post Marco13! Really helped me!